# TFS 2010 and SSMS2012

Tags: sql-server-2012

i was trying to use TFS 2010 in SSMS 2012 and, even if i installed Team Foundation Server MSSCCI Provider 2012 64-bit and Visual Studio 2010 Team Explorer, there's no way  to see TFS under the Current source control plug-in of SSMS.

What can i do to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Simone